# Is there a way to change the volume of sound or turn off sound completely in TuxGuitar?

Tags: software, tuxguitar

In the guitar tabulature software TuxGuitar 1.2, is there a way to completely turn off sound or to adjust the loudness at which playback is done?

Comment: I don't have my laptop in front of me, so I can't fully answer. However, if there is not an option to adjust the volume of the whole program, you could just mute or turn down the individual tracks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is lower the master fader. Push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the mixer:

[image: Mixer window in TuxGuitar 1.2 on Windows 8]

In the mixer you can adjust the volume of different tracks by moving the faders or mute totally by clicking the "Mute" box. To the very right you have the master fader. For some reason it's labeled "Gain" in TuxGuitar as of version 1.2. Lower it to lower all sounds output from TuxGuitar.